# Fetch respective Array's value in same loop iteration

Tags: arrays, loops, dart

```
void main() {
  var n = 5;
  var x = 1;
  var a = [2, 5];

  for (x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    if (x == a[x]) { // on 2nd & 5th iteration it should print 2 & 5 else 0
      print(a[x]);
    } else {
      print(0);
    }
  }
}
```

output should be 0,2,0,0,5.

please note: 2 and 5 should get from array's value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified solution for achieving the result. Logic is, to only check if the element is in the `List` as it iterates.

```
void main() {
  quiz();
}

void quiz() {
  var n = 5;
  var a = [2, 5];
  for(int i = 1;i<=n;i++){
    if(a.contains(i) ){
      print(i);
    }else{
      print(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0
2
0
0
5
```

Comment: thanks dev, but i want to print array's value, instead of index value

Comment: @Rajan logically index_value == array value since that is how we found  equivalence, or is there some constraint that you have?

Comment: i agree here both values are same, but I need to print array' value, please help...

Comment: will the `List` have repeated values or all values will be unique ?

Comment: i can modify the logic to fetch from the `List` using something like this `print('$i, ${a.indexOf(i)}');` . By finding index of the element which is equal to the current value of our iteration index. But that depends on values being unique in the `List` else we will get the index of first occurrence of the element.